# App crashing when I attempt to call speech recognizer

Tags: java, android, crash, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Not really sure why my app crashed? It used to work a year or so ago, but the same code is crashing now. I was running the app on my phone at the time - brand is xiaomi. Is the crash due to an error in its speech recognition software using android.support.v4.widget.Space?

```
2021-07-30 10:58:28.974 12660-12660/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech, PID: 12660
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech/com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech.asr.AsrActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Space
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Space
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Space
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.Space" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech-kCRl1E729EYZZVJ2ACgNsA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech-kCRl1E729EYZZVJ2ACgNsA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech-kCRl1E729EYZZVJ2ACgNsA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2836)
        at com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech.asr.AsrActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
2021-07-30 10:58:28.974 12660-12660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2021-07-30 10:58:28.986 3021-3065/? I/octvm_klo: klo lock
2021-07-30 10:58:28.988 2080-3716/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech/.asr.AsrActivity
```

this is the code used to call the speech recognizer..

```
intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    //Specify language
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
    // Specify language model
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    // Specify how many results to receive
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);

    public void getSpeechInput(View view) {
    Log.i("note", "get speech input");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug in their recognizer activity.  You can catch it and prevent a crash yourself, but I don't think you can do anything to get their activity to launch.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Good to know I can at least catch it and tell users to try a different voice to text app provider